# Visio automatic hyperlink for common label

Tags: visio

I have a wiring diagram drawn in visio that contains many wires (lines) spread over several pages. To follow a certain wire, I often have to jump around multiple pages. The wires always have the same text/label even when propagated to different pages. Normally, I use the find-in-files and type in the specific label I'm hunting for.

It would be even better if I could just click on the wire when it goes off page and a hyperlink would take my to the appropriate place on the appropriate page.

I know how to create hyperlinks manually, but there are a lot of signals and I'd like to somehow automate this, hinged by the fact that the source/destination share a common label.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have rules, where the corresponding shape (link) resides, then you can set up the hyperlink via a SETF(Getref(... formula.

Otherwise, you could use VBA to find the corresponding shape by parsing the whole document and inserting the hyperlink automatically.

HTH,Y.